# Job not being dispatched in test

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm using laravel 8 and Laravel Sail.

I'm trying to test a email that is being sent from a job but is not being sent, no matter what I do. Here's my code

```php
Bus::fake();
Mail::fake();
TheProductDoesNotExists::dispatch($this->channel, $document['product'], $document['name']);
Event::assertDispatched(TheProductDoesNotExists::class);
Mail::assertSent(ProductMissing::class);
```

And I get

```
The expected [App\Mail\ProductMissing] mailable was not sent.
  Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Inside the Job I even have a logger in the handle method but nothing is logged

```
public function handle()
    {
        logger('from the job');
        $alertTo = 'test@test';
        Mail::to($alertTo)->send(
            new ProductMissing($this->product, $this->orderName)
        );
    }
```

And nothing. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Your problem is that you are confusing things, if you are faking the `Event` bus, then you are not going to execute the event... You are mixing 2 tests there, one testing that the event is dispatched and other test that is asserting that the mail is sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `Queue::fake()` or `Bus::fake()`, the framework will replace a real queue (redis, database...) with a SIMPLE ARRAY. All the jobs will be stored in that array and they WILL NOT be executed. The array is used for later assertations. So in your code:

```php
Bus::fake();
Mail::fake();
TheProductDoesNotExists::dispatch($this->channel, $document['product'], $document['name']);
Event::assertDispatched(TheProductDoesNotExists::class);
Mail::assertSent(ProductMissing::class);
```

Because the `TheProductDoesNotExists` is not even executed, then no email is captured and the last line failed.

You can only test one of those two.

```php
Bus::fake();
TheProductDoesNotExists::dispatch($this->channel, $document['product'], $document['name']);
Bus::assertDispatched(TheProductDoesNotExists::class);
```

Or:

```php
Mail::fake()
TheProductDoesNotExists::dispatchNow($this->channel, $document['product'], $document['name']);
Mail::assertSent(ProductMissing::class);
```

Not both at the same time.

For better understanding, I recommend read the `Illuminate\Support\Testing\Fakes\QueueFake` class from the Laravel source code.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! That was it!

Comment: What is the difference between Bus Fake and Queue Fake? What case or when to use each of this Fakes?