# Test laravel job calls another class

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking

I'm trying to test that my laravel 9 job calls another class. I've mocked the class it's expected to call but the test fails with a response that the expected method is not called.
I've tried debugging and can't track that the method appears to be called so something wrong in either the way I'm mocking or using the mock and my test expectations.
So, how do I test that a method within a laravel job calls the method in the class.

Here's the job code:

```
class SendFixtureReminderEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public int $tries = 3;

    /**
     * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public int $timeout = 240;

    private League $league;
    private Fixture $fixture;
    private FixtureReminderEmail $fixtureReminderEmail;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(League $league)
    {
        $this->league = $league;

        $this->fixtureReminderEmail = app()->make(FixtureReminderEmail::class, ['league'=>$this->league]);

    }

    /**
     * Get the tags that should be assigned to the job.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return ['fixtureReminderEmail'];
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {

        $counter = $this->fixtureReminderEmail->handle();

        Log::info($counter . " Fixture " . Str::plural('reminder', $counter) .  "sent");
    }
}
```

and here's the latest version of my test:

```
class SendFixtureReminderJobTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    use WithFaker;

    private $adminUser;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     * @covers SendEclecticUpdateEmailJob::handle
     * @description:
     */
    public function testHandle()
    {
        Queue::fake();

        $league = League::factory()->matchplay()->create();

        $this->mock(FixtureReminderEmail::class, function($mock) use ($league) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('handle')
                ->with($league)
                ->once()
                ->andReturn(6);

        });

        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $job = new SendFixtureReminderEmailJob($league);

        $job->dispatch($league);


    }
}
```

Any help in developing a test that the job calls the class would be great :)

**Update:**
I'm adding the variations i've recently tried to test that the job calls the method on the mock based on the help within comments:

*with DispatchSyn*
to avoid the queue and removed queue::fake

```
    public function testHandle()
    {
//        Queue::fake();

        $league = League::factory()->matchplay()->create();

        $this->mock(FixtureReminderEmail::class, function($mock) use ($league) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('handle')
                ->with($league)
                ->once()
                ->andReturn(6);

        });

        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $job = new SendFixtureReminderEmailJob($league);

        $job->dispatchSync($league);

//        Queue::assertPushed(SendFixtureReminderEmailJob::class, 1);

    }
```

and this version by calling the jobs handle:

```
    public function testHandle()
    {
//        Queue::fake();

        $league = League::factory()->matchplay()->create();

        $this->mock(FixtureReminderEmail::class, function($mock) use ($league) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('handle')
                ->with($league)
                ->once()
                ->andReturn(6);

        });

        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $job = new SendFixtureReminderEmailJob($league);

        $job->handle($league);

//        Queue::assertPushed(SendFixtureReminderEmailJob::class, 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: It is bcs at first line of your test you have  Queue::fake(); 
what it does is adding the jobs in array and not execute them ! 
for better understanding read this ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452015/job-not-being-dispatched-in-test

Comment: Why not just manually call the job handle method as there is no need to test the framework code because it is already tested heavily by the laravel team.

Comment: @Atabarzegar thank you.  That makes sense and I can see by using `queue::assertPushed(SendFixtureReminderEmailJob` is pushed to the queue - which means my approach is wrong as I want to test the job does what it's meant to. I changed `$job->dispatch()` to `$job->dispatchSync()` and removed 'queue::fake` - the mock assertions continue to fail and the method is not called.

Comment: @AdamGriffith thank you. I did start there originally with using `$job->handle($league);` - I've removed the `queue::fake()` and still continues to fail on the mock assertions that the method is not being called.

Comment: I think found it ! 
in your mock object you have a method with name of 'with' 
and here you say my handle method (I mean handle of FixtureReminderEmail ) will get an argument , but actully you call it without any argument !

test it , if it is true I will write complete answer

Comment: @Atabarzegar - thanks for helping :). Just tried that and removed the `with` but sadly still no call the the handle method in the target class.

Comment: tried with   $job->handle($league)  or        $job->dispatchSync($league) ?

Comment: Yes, it fails to call the method in the class when using handle or dispatchSync :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved.**

I carried on tinkering and creating the `FixtureReminderEmail` class within the test, bypassing the job to see what happened and it still failed.

I'm now going to kick myself as it was failing because of the way I was instantiating the class. I was using `new` to create the new object whereas to enable Laravel to swap out the class with the mock object, in the Job class I should have used:

```
$reminder = app()->make(FixtureReminderEmail::class);

$reminder->handle($league);
```

It failed the first time when I tried using `dispatchNow()` with a reflection error but as @adamGriffin comment I don't want to test the framework, just my class does what it's meant to and reverted to calling the handle method on the job :)